# React useeffect missing dependencies for update the first item in array

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have a list and when there is a new item in the list(only if the list empty) that comes from redux and the event array is being updated I want to select the new item, update the list, and the redux state.

1- is there another clean way to choose the selected event on new event?
2- do I need a different use effect when all the list finished(and not empty) to load the list and then also = set the selected by some condition?

I have the following useEffect: (I want to choose the selected only once)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (events.length === 1) {
      if (events[0].image) {
        updateSelectedIndex(events[0].imageId);
        dispatch(setCurrentEvent(events[0].imageId));
      }
    }
  }, [events[0], dispatch]);
```

**I got the warning:**

```
  Line 88:6:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'events'. Either include it or remove the dependency array
```

Do I really need to fix it? if I added the events to the dependencies it means that any change will enter to the effect and will do nothing because of the condition ? does it really matter?

Answer (score 0):

Don't listen on `events[0]` but just on events. It does not matter if it enters the effect, because due to your condition it won't do anything.

Comment: but then it will enter to the condition `events[0].image !== null` evrey cycle . and I need it once

Comment: If you *only* need it once, how about setting a flag that you assign after you did it the first time? Or ask yourself why you need to use an Effect, and not a useState that you call from where the event is coming from

Comment: yes, the event is being updated a few times- and only if the image is ready I need to apply it,  how do you suggest handling it. ?

Comment: When `events[0].image !== null` is true the first time, you can simply either assign the image to a variable, or assign a true value to a flag like `isImageHandled` and use that as your condition.

Comment: but in re-render it will assign again ? no ?

Comment: Not if you use a useRef

Comment: @nicloai can you show me an example about useRef? thx